# How to merge table rows data based on same column value

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have table name abc and it's columns are

```
id    table_row_name   a     b    c
1     user             1     1    Null
2     user             Null  Null 1
```

How can I merge into one record with query like below and what will be the laravel  way of doing it

```
      table_row_name   a     b    c
      user             1     1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below  query

```
select table_row_name, max(a) as a, max(b) as b, max(c) as c
from tablename
group by table_row_name
```

Comment: Do you know how to achieve this in eloquent or query builder of laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by this query:

```
\DB::table('abc')
        ->select([
            'table_row_name',
            \DB::raw('MAX(a) as a'),
            \DB::raw('MAX(b) as b'),
            \DB::raw('MAX(c) as c')
        ])
        ->groupBy('table_row_name')
        ->get();
```

Comment: what if you want to select all of the columns but only want to group by on of them?